# Why didn't 6 reviewers' recommendations delete this answer?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175686/how-do-i-run-a-graphical-application-on-a-remote-server-when-logged-in-through-s/175691#175691) was flagged as low quality and [reviewed](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/782950) by 7 users. All but one reviewer *Recommended Deletion*, and the review now claims to be completed, both on the review page and on the [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/175691/timeline), but *the post was not deleted*.

In case the review link is not public, here is a screenshot:

[image: review page showing 6 users recommended deletion, including the last]

The last user voted to delete the answer, and that completed the review, but the post withstood the onslaught.

Why did this post survive this review? (Are Eliah Kagan's votes magic?)

Comment: In case anybody's wondering, I voted "Looks OK" because the answer suggests to use a command-line editor, which the OP or other readers may not have thought of, if they're accustomed to editing files with graphical text editors. This is to say that [I think it's reasonable](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41561337#41561337) to consider the question partly [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). But it should've *at least* stayed in the queue for more reviews, if for some reason the review system deliberately doesn't always delete on the sixth recommendation.

Comment: I had voted to close that anwer because it reads as more of a comment on the accepted answer, and the use of text editors is covered in the past paragraph of *that* answer.

Comment: I _think_ (but I'm not sure) that if someone says "Looks OK" it takes at least one more "delete" vote to work.

Comment: @TheWanderer that's reasonable, but if more voters were needed, I wouldn't expect the review to complete without waiting for them!

Comment: Side note; Reviews are always public, even for guest users and even for deleted posts. Though in case of deleted posts, only the review stats are available, but the post would show as not found. For example, try checking the following link in private mode which shows "Answer not found": https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/768004

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the answer has positive score (+1 at the moment). This means that if reviewers agree it should be deleted, the deletion will not happen immediately; instead, an automatic flag for moderator review is raised.  [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861):

> If the outcome of review is deletion, and a post's score prevents it from being deleted, the original flags will be marked "helpful". In these cases, and in cases where the flags are disputed, a new, moderator-only flag will be raised on the post.

For this reason, I occasionally go out of my way (and out of the queue) to also downvote the answer that I recommend for deletion, if it currently has positive score.

Comment: [status-bydesign]! I also always downvote the post if it has a positive score (and any time I visit the link to the actual post when reviewing) if I myself think it should be deleted. If the score goes from 1 to 0 and I refresh the review page, I'm then able to cast a 20k delete vote, which is one of several reasons for doing it. Now I know another one. Thanks a lot.